# Proving statistical significance in the number of games won against another team

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, reinforcement-learning

I trained a reinforcement learning agent to learn a collaborative game played in teams. Then I let it play against another team and now I want to prove that a) the number of games won differs significantly from 50 % (meaning that the result of the games is not just random) and b) that one team won significantly more games than the other team. Could you please give me an input on which statistical tests to use in order to prove statistical significance? And also how you would set up these tests?

Comment: I recommend looking into the proportion z-test for comparing your proportion to $50\%$ and the chi-squared test for comparing the groups. Perhaps read about those and post back here to say if those do or do not meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks @Dave. So concerning the proportion z-test would you compare the proportion of the winners (group a) to a fictional group b with a 50/50 proportion?

Comment: I do have another question. Assuming I did three different experiments, all of them giving me a certain win percentage over the same number of games. Is there a way of comparing these experiments and saying, whether the outcome of one experiment is significantly better than the other?

Comment: To your first question, the proportion z-test has a two-sample variant and a one-sample variant. When you have one sample, use the one-sample variant. // To your second question, please ask a separate question, but the answer is that you can and it will be like ANOVA.